# How to reproduce android monkey crash?

Tags: android, command-line, adb, monkey

i test the smart phone of android, in command line mode for input :

```
adb shell monkey -v 10000

the result is----------------------------------------------------------------------<start>:
procrank:
// Exception from procrank:
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [procrank] Working Directory: null Environment: null
......
.........
.
..
...
.............
// anr traces status was 0
meminfo:
// meminfo status was 0
** Monkey aborted due to error.
Events injected: 21566
:Dropped: keys=6938 pointers=14444 trackballs=0 flips=0
## Network stats: elapsed time=454194ms (0ms mobile, 0ms wifi, 454194ms not connected)
** System appears to have crashed at event 21566 of 1000000 using seed 0

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<end>
```

Could i reproduce the event that 21566 of 100000 using seed 0?

and just do the single event 21566 of 100000?

(someone tell me the method that "adb shell am start",but i am not proficient this command.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using monkey to reproduce errors, it may need to do all the events that it did in the previous run in order to reproduce the error. Since the error may be a cause of the entire chain of events (i.e. changing settings, starting/stopping apps..).

A monkey event may be as simple as a touch command at a certain position, and if its not in the exact correct application with the correct settings it may not cause the error.

In some cases it could be the effect of one event that makes it stop. For example, if the event is starting an app and that app always crashes then that one event will most likely fail every time.